# Autofill if name = hash

Tags: python, hash, mechanize, autofill

I am trying to autofill a text box(multiple boxes) in a form using mechanize in python, but the name of the box(es) is a hash, so I can't automate the input like br.form['name'] = 'blah' since the name is an unknown hash from a hash function. Is there any way to do this? I've looked online and haven't been able to find anything. Thanks!

Comment: does the hash change everytime? In This case mechanize won't work.

Comment: oh darn. Is there any way to locate the input using something particular to it, such as 'size =' or is there anything other than mechanize that could do this?

Comment: There is definitely a way to do this.  I am searching through old code for a solution I came up with for this exact problem (field names inconsistently named, but searchable via regex)

Comment: I've thought of a method, check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.  Obviously you will need to update the `predicate` method.  Also, do you have any constant information about the field(s)?  id, class, label, etc?

```
import mechanize
import re

class MyBrowser:

    def __init__(self):
        self.user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)'
        self.cj = mechanize.LWPCookieJar()
        self.setup_browser(enable_debug=False)

    def find_by_crazy_name(self, control):
        if re.match('^[\w]{32,}$', control.name):
            return True
        return False

    def runit(self):
        self.agent.open('http://localhost')
        self.agent.select_form(name="foo")
        field = self.agent.form.find_control(predicate=self.find_by_crazy_name)
        field._value = "POOP"
        response = self.agent.submit()

    def enable_debug(self):
        self.agent.set_debug_http(True)
        self.agent.set_debug_redirects(True)
        self.agent.set_debug_responses(True)

    def setup_browser(self, enable_debug=False):
        self.agent = mechanize.Browser()
        self.agent.set_handle_redirect(True)
        self.agent.set_cookiejar(self.cj)
        self.agent.set_handle_referer(True)
        self.agent.set_handle_refresh(True)
        self.agent.set_handle_equiv(True)
        self.agent.set_handle_robots(False)
        self.enable_debug()
        self.agent.addheaders = [('User-Agent', self.user_agent)]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    browser = MyBrowser()
    browser.runit()
```

This just fills out all potential field with "POOP".  A field is a match if is is 32 alphanumeric characters (like an md5)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `br.form` is a dictionary, you can iterate over the keys to set a default for all fields in the form:

```
for key in br.form:
    br.form[key] = 'blah'
```

If you only want to fill in the default for your unknown field, I'm assuming you would know all of the other field names, so you could do something like this:

```
known_fields = set(['foo', 'bar'])  # put your known keys in here
for key in br.form:
    if key not in known_fields:
        # this must be the hash
        br.form[key] = 'blah'
```

Note that this assumes that your hash field already exists in `br.form`, probably with a `None` or empty string value.  I haven't used mechanize so I'm not sure whether or not this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

If the requested form has always the same amount of forms you can find it by the form number (0 beeing the first form and so on)

Try `br.select_form(nr=number)`

Comment: This will select the form, not the form fields which is what the OP is after.